# Assign a zero value on an array when an empty result has been returned from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Can I assign "0" value on an array that returned no results from a MySQL Query?

If so, can you show me how?

my code goes something like this:

```
    $grapes_query = mysql_query("SELECT fruitDate, fruitName, COUNT(*) FROM tbl_fruits WHERE fruitName='Grapes' GROUP BY 

    fruitDate");
    while ($grapes = mysql_fetch_assoc($grapes_query)){
    $grapes_array[]=$grapes['COUNT(*)'];

}
```

What if in a day, no grapes were found, can I assign "0" to its array value?

Let's say 1/1/2012 = 3 grapes were counted,  1/2/2012 = no grapes were counted,  1/3/2012 = 5 grapes were counted..so the array should be like this.

```
$grapes_array[0]=3;
$grapes_array[1]= <-- i want to assign a string or number here when a MySQL query is empty.
$grapes_array[2]=3;
```

i'm getting errors if no value was found.

UPDATE:

[image]

fruit names should be grapes...:(

UPDATE 2:

HERE is my sample database being used.

[image]

Here is the result I'm getting on your updated query

[image]

Comment: Assign "0" value in what way? I think you need to clarify what you really want.

Comment: in a string or number type, whichever of these will work.

Comment: I;ve edited my question..hope this is clear...

Comment: Is your query working correctly what does Count(*) return when there is no group by.

Comment: it skips the empty array..and assigns [0]=3 and [1]=3..instead of [0]=3, [1]=0, [2]=3..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated query will provide dates where there are fruit counts, but no Grapes counted on that day

```
$grapes_query = mysql_query("SELECT f.fruitDate, IF(ISNULL(f1.count), 0, f1.count) as count FROM tbl_fruits f
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT fruitName, fruitDate, COUNT(*) as count from tbl_fruits d WHERE d.fruitName='Grapes' GROUP BY d.fruitDate) as f1 ON (f.fruitDate = f1.fruitDate) 
    GROUP BY f.fruitDate");
while ($grapes = mysql_fetch_assoc($grapes_query)){
   // use the fruitDate as a key for the array
   $grapes_array[$grapes['fruitDate']]= $grapes['count'];

}
```

Comment: It seems to be working BUT..I'm getting different fruit name on my query...I've attached a screenshot on my question for reference.

Comment: I have added a condition to the left join so that you match the name of the fruit too, sorry had missed that

Comment: can we display 0 instead of Null?

Comment: Updated the query to show 0 instead of null, and removed the intval() in the while loop. Do you have any records for grapes on any of the dates which show 0?

Comment: yeah.. i have grapes for March 1 and 3..lemme show you a screenshot..BTW..the display of 0 is working..

Comment: The fruitName cannot be accurately determined, so I have also removed it from the query. Since you show data for only one fruit, then you will know that they are Grapes or any other fruit that will be added as a filter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8491/discussion-between-tristan-jade-awat-and-ssmusoke)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

- Select the minimum and maximum date from the table
- Fill your output array with date => 0 pairs (initialize every date to zero)
- Run your script, but instead of creating a new numeric index with `[]`, use the date as a key